# overwrote ~/bin folder

Tags: file-recovery

Somehow I accidentally overwrote my `~/bin`.

I typed the command: `$ cp /home/dsg/Downloads/sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar ~/bin`

I was trying to copy the file into my `bin` folder but instead overwrote the folder.

Now:

```
$ cd ~/bin
bash: cd: /home/dsg/bin: Not a directory
```

And:

```
$ diff /home/dsg/Downloads/sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar ~/bin
```

Shows no differences.

What do I do?

Comment: Restore from backup?

Comment: No backup. Is there a way to restore to default? It is almost a fresh install, so there shouldn't have been much there. I am trying to avoid a reinstall of the whole system.

Comment: @dsg: *By default, `~/bin` does not exist.* You must have created it yourself. `rm -f ~/bin && mkdir ~/bin`

Comment: To add to grawity's comment, if ~/bin had existed as a directory prior to the cp command, the cp command would have copied the .jar file into ~/bin, not replaced ~/bin. So I don't think there was a ~/bin directory before the cp command.

Comment: Oh, excellent! Thanks! @garyjohn , confirmed. I have just `rm ~/bin` and `mkdir ~/bin`, and now when I do a copy the file is moved into the directory as you say.

Comment: @dsg: if that resolved your question, you should add it as an answer and then accept it (or even better, @grawity should do it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you copy a file using the command you used:

```
$ cp /home/dsg/Downloads/sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar ~/bin
```

different things happen depending on what the target is.

1) ~/bin is a directory

The file will be copied into the ~/bin directory keeping the original name of the file.

2) ~/bin is a regular file

The file ~/bin will be overwritten by the source file.

3) ~/bin does not exist

The source file will be copied to the destination name creating a new file.

By default the ~/bin directory doesn't exist, so unless you created a directory at some time in the past called ~/bin then option 3 will be what happened.  If there was a ~/bin in existance, then for the `cp` command to overwrite it it must have been a regular file and not a directory.

You should delete the ~/bin file and create a directory with:

```
$ rm ~/bin
$ mkdir ~/bin
```

Then you can copy the jar file into it with the same command you used before.

(Thanks to @grawity and @garyjohn on whose comments to the question this answer was based upon.)